# Masking/Padding the labels of a CNN | Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am working on a facial landmark detection CNN. The dataset consist of images with 15 landmarks (each with x,y coordinates) and some images that only have labels for 4 of those 15 landmarks.

Instead of filling the missing values or only training on the clean data I want to use padding and masking for the output layer to only train on the labels that are there for any given image. For example for images with only 4 labels the model should just ignore the other outputs for calculating the loss and backpropagating.

Currently the model architecture looks something like this:

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, BatchNormalization, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, MaxPool2D, LeakyReLU

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False, input_shape=(96, 96, 1)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# more Conv2d layers and so on....

model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(30))
```

How do I do this with keras? Is there a somehow "proper way" to do it without writing my own loss function?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom loss function. A trick could be to set the masking value to -1. (or -1) in y_true (input labels)

```
def mycustomloss(y_true, y_pred):
  loss = tf.abs(y_true - y_pred)  # Mean Abolute Error as an example, put your loss here, without reduction!
  loss = tf.where(y_true !=-1., loss, 0.)
  return tf.reduce_mean(loss)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=mycustomloss)
```

Pay attention to the type of the labels (integers or floats) and plug your loss as shown without reduction, i.e. same input and output shapes

Comment: Thanks. That was the way I thought of how I _could_ do it but I thought there was a different and "proper way" how to do it in keras. With a masking layer or something.

Comment: A masking layer is usually used with RNNs for variable length sequences. I don't think you can do something similar here because the *output* (y_true) needs masking and the loss function needs to be modified accordingly.

Comment: I implemented your idea but sadly the model performs significantly worse...
There is definitely a logical mistake here. I don't want to set the absolute error to 0 for all those values. They are disrupting the mean that way. Instead I want to discard them. I think I found a better solution I will post here later.

Comment: `tf.abs` is not differentiable so you won't have backprop

Comment: what about relu?

Comment: @elbe relu is fine. more context: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/26426/why-is-tf-abs-non-differentiable-in-tensorflow
You should get warnings about non-differentiable functions in general when you try to train the model.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is no other way then to write your own loss function like this for example (it really depends on how you want to deal with the values):

```py
def masked_mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred):
    """Returns the mean absolute error between y_true and y_pred, ignoring all the data where y_true is -1."""
    mask = tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.equal(y_true, tf.constant(-1.)))
    loss = tf.abs(y_true - y_pred)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.ragged.boolean_mask(loss, mask), 1)
```